# Why did my account get merged with several others? What do I have to do to reverse it?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I just logged in and found that my account was merged with many other accounts with no reason. My account has many questions that don't belong to my account. I don't know why it happened. There are also no notifications in my inbox that say why my account was merged with them. What do I have to do to reverse this?

For now, I just removed the login from those other account to prevent them from logging in to my account. I think that is the right thing to do. If it isn't, please tell me, what do I have to do?

Update: I already contacted the staff through [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) at about the same time I asked the question.

Update 2: After I read some comment, I think my account get merged because I use the network that many people also use it too. (It is dormitory's net.) And many people login in the same time without knowing about each other.

Update 3: I just receive the answer from SE support in my E-mail. They say my account get merged because the system detect that the other account are sock-puppet. But they aren't sock-puppet. They are really other people account who share same IP address with my IP. Here is one of [their question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309925/kuzco-pots-stack-problem). And here is [their another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521825/the-hardest-geometry-question-with-a-triangle-and-a-circle-circle-intersec). I don't understand those question but those questions are asked by real other persons for sure.

Result: Sorry for late update. I don't have enough time. Here is the answer for SE staff.

> Unfortunately, even if the merges are a mistake, there is a point where the behavior we observe - and the evidence surrounding account ownership - becomes indistinguishable from malice, and we've crossed the threshold here. As a result, we will not be reversing these account merges. In the event these accounts do not in fact belong to you, we always recommend that in cases like this (such as spouses, co-workers, close friends, relatives, or roommates) that one doesn't upvote or interact with the others' content at all.

At least I do my best. I do find some of them whose account get merge to my account. No one happy with that. We have to talk to each other to avoid interacting each other. I think they interact with each other too much. Anyway, all of them don't get any warning before the merging.

However, one of them say that he create his account few days ago, ask a question and then lost his account. All of us never interact with him. He also login in different time but his account get merged to my account. I think when the system decide to merge accounts, it will merge all account from that IP no matter if that account interact with other account from that IP or not. That is bad but I don't think I can do anything to change that.

This is my story. I hope it will help anyone who has the same situation as me and avoid this.

Comment: Please contact the staff using this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: That's very odd. You should use the contact button at the bottom of any page and leave a message for the staff to look at it. They should have a record of who made the request to merge the accounts in the first place. There's always a queue so you may need to wait until after the weekend for a response.  - You might want to double check the security of your E-Mail password to ensure that your friends/family aren't playing tricks on you.

Comment: @Random Person Which topic do I have to choose on that contact page ?

Comment: @RoTheory choose "Other" and explain what happened

Comment: @W.O. There is nothing say about who request to merge my account and other in my inbox. I am not sure but there is no suspicious login that the security say in my E-mail.

Comment: It's automatic, usually. But can you please give example of old question that appears now in your account that you didn't ask yourself? This way we might be able to track down the original asker, and you can also give this info to SE staff.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Here is the one that I didn't ask https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309925/kuzco-pots-stack-problem It was ask by someone else in about 3 years ago.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard What does "It's automatic" mean ? Do you mean my account was merged automatically ? I don't know anything about merging and why or how it happen

Comment: Yes this usually happens when, for example, the system detects you are logged in with two accounts in same time in same browser session. Just a wild guess, but maybe the other person got the same IP address as yours, and was active in the same time, which can trigger such a merge, in theory.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Oh, that is bad. I use the network that many people also use it too. It is dormitory's net. I think someone else login in the same time as me or other account.

Comment: @RoTheory this is true, shared network cause lots of trouble when IP address is the same, and used to identify users. (Not only that of course, I believe when you submit contact form they'll be able to help.)

Comment: IP addresses may be shared by 100's or 1000's of users. Substantially more than merely a sharing an IP address is required for a merge, either automatically or manually. A moderator on a site where you have a profile/account *may* have more information about what happened, but probably shouldn't be sharing it here. Anyone other than such a moderator or staff is just *guessing* as to what *might* have happened, and even moderators may be making educated guesses, but with, hopefully, a bit more information. Your best course of action, as has already been mentioned is the "contact us" route.

Comment: @Makyen Is it really possible for 1000's of users to share same IP address without getting merged ? Two or more accounts might login in same time and trigger the merge. In my case, I think it is because two or more accounts login in same time.

Comment: @RoTheory It's necessary for basically any semi-reasonable number of accounts to be able to share the same IP address without bad/unusual things happening in order for a website the size of SE to function normally. There will be traffic restrictions, in order to prevent DOS attacks, etc., but keeping accounts separate, even if they are using the same IP address, is a normal thing for any website. As I said earlier, *any* information you've gotten here as to what might have happened is *just people guessing*. The only real information which you *might* get is from staff through "contact us".

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Just sharing an IP is not enough for a merge, not by a longshot. Your statement is causing confusion for OP. You can login with multiple users on the same device *at the same time*, just keep their browser profiles separate (or use different browsers altogether). It's also important to logout when you're done on a shared device or who knows what others will do with your account.

Comment: @Mast I disagree. Legit "socks" don't get merged for the sole reason the owners are careful not to interact with each other. But when it's actually several different people on same IP, they do vote on same posts and do more actions that triggers "sock account" alert, raise flags, and get themselves merged and/or suspended.

Comment: Anyway there's nothing we can do, the one and only answer was already given in the duplicate, as well as here: **contact support**. Now that you have, reply to them via email.

Comment: Related (the time correlation and the merge of more than two accounts may or may not be coincidental): *[This suspension was not fair since my friend didn't want to merge 3 accounts for convenience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420316/)* - *"This was an extremely large fraud scheme"*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum with millions of users, I think it can be coincidental. Some people cheat, some don't. In this case, I still believe the OP is telling the truth.

Comment: *"we've crossed the threshold here. As a result, we will not be reversing these account merges"* What a mess! I don't understand how not reversing the merge is helpful. I suppose some of the people in your dorm have been upvoting your posts and each others' posts. Although it's natural to upvote your friends, Stack Exchange does *not* approve of that behaviour. It's not a social network, it's an anti-social network. ;)

Answer (score 18):

If your account was merged with another account and you believe it to have been done in error, send a question to us via the ["Contact Us" form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) (also found in the footer of any page), and we'll handle it on a case-by-case basis. We won't generally answer these questions in public, because account merges often concern user PII, which means there will typically be details we are restricted from sharing here.

I do need to disclaim in advance that account merges are *very rarely* an error, whether they happen automatically, by request, or by staff review. We may, under certain circumstances, be able to offer insight into why a merge was done.

Comment: I do send the "Contact Support" 4 hours ago but haven't received anything in my E-mail for now. It is possible that I might not provide enough information since I am very contused at that time. What are the information that I have to add ?

Comment: @RoTheory Might wanna give folks a bit longer than four hours. It can take a couple business days to reply - and it's a Friday afternoon.

Comment: I am sorry. I am so worried about that it might be too late to be fixed. Is there a limit time for this to be reversed ?

Comment: @RoTheory Don't worry, these things aren't time sensitive. It may take a bit, but SE staff will get you sorted. :)

Comment: @RoTheory but what actual harm is done? You can still ask questions and post answers. Your privileges were not affected. Of course this should be resolved, one way or another, but don't think it's really that urgent.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Yeah but the "really other people" have lost their accounts. Although they aren't complaining. Or they are.

Comment: @philipxy well, yes, but that's not the responsibility of the OP. Also, good chance those are "one time hitters", that posted something never to come back.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard The problem is that those people live in the same dormitory as me. It is like many of your neighbor's bank account are closed and all their money go to my accounts by the system. None of them will be ok with that for sure. Me too. I am not a person who is ok when I get some thing by the error of the system. And it is a matter of time that they will know that where their upvote and their question go. At least, I can show them that I do my best to help them.

Comment: @philipxy They share them as network as me and live in the same dormitory as me. It is a matter of time that they will find me. And I am very sure that they will complaining. No one is ok with that.

Comment: @RoTheory so gather them up, and ask them to also contact SE support (contact form) and help you prove your point. Blaming you won't help their cause. If they do it, better ask them to use different device, e.g. their mobile phone, to help identify they're actually different people, and not you.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I will try.