# Is it OK to create a timetable to avoid getting merged when I have to share the same network with other people?

Tags: discussion, support, merge-accounts

I stay in a dormitory and have a problem: I have to share the same network with four other people. We know each other's accounts and avoid interacting with each other. The problem is even though we know and don't interact with each other, it is possible that we might log in at the very same time too many times and get merged. It happened, and I don't want it to happen again.

So, I decided to create a timetable. Here it is. (Total five people. Me and four other people.)

- Account A: 19:00-19:55
- Account B: 20:00-20:55
- Account C: 21:00-21:55
- Account D: 22:00-22:55
- Account E: 23:00-23:55

We all start using the Internet during 19:00-24:00, so we have to share those times with each other.

Each account has 55 minutes. There is a 5-minutes gap between each account.

Is that is 5-minutes gap enough? If not, what should it be? And if I should not create a timetable, what should I do?

Comment: It's less about using the site in same time, more about interacting with each other when it appears to be the same source/person. I'm using sock accounts, sometimes three, together with my actual account, to test stuff. I'm just being super careful to not do any interaction between them, and it's fine. Can't give official response though, so better wait to see if SE staff will give such.

Comment: The rules about interactions between alternate accounts are about what actions are permitted/not permitted. The rules are not about when you perform those actions. I'd strongly suggest you focus on making the actions which the accounts take be compliant with the rules for using alternate accounts (regardless of if the accounts are alternates of yours or actually other people), rather than ignoring those rules and focusing on the times the actions are taken.

Comment: (Related question: *[Are these actions counted as "interactions"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382321/are-these-actions-counted-as-interactions)*)

Comment: Since the Stack Exchange Staff [don't believe these accounts are anything other than your sock puppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381936/188189), I doubt using them in a timetable is going to help. Worse than that it's actually more evidence that there's a single controlling mind operating all of them if they behave in such a way.

Comment: I’ve been to college and lived in a dormitory with other computer science students. This is not how they live their lives. This post is not even remotely believable.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov In your case, do other computer science students also use SE too ? Anyway, I live in different country from you. And not every dormitory is same.

Comment: @RoTheory Very frequently, an entire campus will have a single or narrow set of external IP addresses it uses to access the internet. I don't think it's reaching to say that if a given school has a Comp. Sci. program, that there will be _many_, _many_ students using SE/ SO at the same time. Considering that errant account merges aren't a common complaint among university students across Stack Exchange, your argument is less convincing than you seem to think. Time is not the factor here, cross-account influence and actions are.

Answer (score 10):

Its got nothing to do with time - I've had my alternate account (which is clearly labelled and used for looking at things from an untrusted computer or a non moderator view) logged in at the same time, and the same PC (in incognito mode). Even the email's obviously similar enough. Its never been merged.

There's probably *other* suspicious activity involved

I'd note incorrect merges have happened. They are *deeply* embarrassing and *swiftly fixed*. Generally though I'd trust the community team - who have *certainly looked at the full extent of information provided* and drawn their conclusions based on evidence.

I can't imagine that a dorm full of people are in any way likely to literally keep their usage of a site to exactly one hour a day, and most 'innocent' activity, like looking up information would be a pain to do that way.

Assuming it was sock puppet voting that was the actual issue, might I suggest just giving a cookie if your co-dorm-mates posts were helpful?